# Where does this method's arguments get passed from?

Tags: objective-c, ios, methods

Simple question: where do the `tableView` and `section` arguments get passed from? The actual code in the method `return [self.listData count];` doesn't even mention them.

Here's my interface code:

```
@interface Simple_TableViewController : UIViewController 
<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
{   
NSArray *listData;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *listData;

@end
```

And this is all the implementation code:

```
#import "Simple_TableViewController.h"

@implementation Simple_TableViewController
@synthesize listData;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Sleepy", @"Sneezy", 
                  @"Bashful", @"Happy", @"Doc", @"Grumpy", @"Dopey", @"Thorin", 
                  @"Dorin", @"Nori", @"Ori", @"Balin", @"Dwalin", @"Fili", @"Kili",
                  @"Oin", @"Gloin", @"Bifur", @"Bofur", @"Bombur", nil];
self.listData = array;
[array release];
[super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
self.listData = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
[listData release];
[super dealloc];
    }


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table View Data Source Methods
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [self.listData count];
}
```

I just want to know how does the method `(NSInteger)tableView: (UITableView *)numberOfRowsInSection:` receive those arguments? Of course this happens everywhere; I just want to understand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Simple_TableViewController class is likely meant to manage a single table with a single section. Given that, the tableView and section parameters aren't important because they can only be one thing: a pointer to the table and 0, respectively.

Comment: This is true, but does that mean all arguments in all methods aren't required? Or do they have defaults? Also, I know that method is triggered through the delegate, but how do I know which event does the triggering?

Comment: The table data source has to implement certain methods with specific interfaces. -tableView:numberOfRowsInSection: is a good example -- the data source doesn't get to rewrite the method name to eliminate unneeded parameters -- if it did, how would UITableView know what method to call? So, in this case, the table is giving its data source more information than it needs to answer the question "How many rows are there?" The method isn't obligated to use all its parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Your view controller class is adding support for these callback methods through UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource. You are adding this support in your .h file through `<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>`. These classes are built in to the Cocoa Touch framework and you are just using them. When the table is (re)loaded, this callback methods are called if you have defined them (some are required, others are optional).